# Pass variable from theme page template to commerce-product file

Tags: commerce

I am new to drupal and this is my first website in drupal. 
I am looking to pass a variable from newtheme.theme to commerce-product.html.twig but I am not able to do so.

Here is my code (newtheme is name of my theme)

```
function newtheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
 $variables['product_cta'] = 'Static Text';
}
```

in commerce-product.html.twig

```
{{product_cta}}
```

but this is not working  the product_cta will be a call to action which will be calculated programmatically and passed to the product single page.
I am using Drupal 8 and Commerce 2.X.X

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the next function in your theme / module:

```
function YOURT_HEME_preprocess_commerce_product(&$variables) {
 $variables['product_cta'] = 'Static Text';
}

function YOURT_MODULE_preprocess_commerce_product(&$variables) {
 $variables['product_cta'] = 'Static Text';
}
```

And show the variables in the commerce-product.html.twig file:

```
{{ product_cta }}
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache after you created the new function if you didn't.

If It still not working, create a [new module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/a-practical-guide-to-building-basic-drupal-8-modules) and place the preprocess_page function into the module